# Formatting The Binary Y-Labels When Padding Input Data For LSTM Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I currently have a multiple data of sequence of images that say looks something like this:

`image_sequence = [nsamples, nchannels, width, height]`,
 where

- nchannels = 4
- width = 64
- height = 64
- nsamples = 500-1000

`ylabels = [nsamples]` (0, or 1 at every image)

So essentially, I have multiple recordings of varying **image_sequences**, with the only variable being the number of samples in the **image_sequence**. My understanding for **Keras** is that nsamples needs to be padded to some degree (e.g.

```
newimage_seq = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(image_sequence, 
               maxlen, padding='pre', truncating='pre', value=0.)
```

I have a few questions:

1. (**Main Question**) However, how would I go about padding my ylabels also? If I pad the beginning with 0s, should I also pad the ylabels with 0?
2. (**Secondary Questions**) Then if I build up a dataset of sequences of images, as **[#datasets, maxlen, nchannels, width, height]**, and ylabels of shape **[#datasets, maxlen]**, then how would I train my neural network of just say an **LSTM** (just flatten all image features, for sake of simplicity). Would the #datasets be the sample dimension, and then maxlen would be the time dimension?

For example, I would pad the ylabels as such?

```
newy_seq = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(ylabels, 
                   maxlen, padding='pre', truncating='pre', value=0.)
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `y` label?

Comment: ylabel is just 0 or 1 of a binary class prediction. So say 0 is normal, and 1 is an event we want to detect.

Comment: So - is assumption that padded part of sequence belong to class `0` right?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko, yes if I pad 0's to the ylabels, I guess I would have to label them as part of class 0... but I'm wondering if this is the correct approach since I am predicting classes for each window within the sequence versus the traditional problem of predicting a class for a certain sequence.

Comment: You could set the padded sequence to `0`, original `0` class to `1` and class `1` to class `2` and the set the class weight of `0` to `0` - this will prevent your network from learning useless padding patterns.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko how we could set the class weight differently? (considering a simple sequential model in Keras)